# reading depth in mm from ros depth image

Tags: ros, opencv, depth-image

I want to read a depth image from ros.
I subscribe to the `/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw/compressed` topic published by a intel realsense D435i camera.
I get a sensor_msgs CompressedImage ros msg, the image has a `16UC1; jpeg compressed` format.
I use opencv to read the image:
`depth_image = bridge.compressed_imgmsg_to_cv2(image_depth,desired_encoding='passthrough')`
but it returns an image with values between 0-255. How can I get the depth value in mm for each pixel?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/issues/2361#issuecomment-1160149057 and surrounding comments say to use `compressedDepth` instead, or  uncompressed, `/compressed` `16UC1; jpeg compressed` is unusable (because it was automatically created by `ImageTransport`, which in this case and others creates invalid image topics unless manually configured not to with `disable_pub_plugins`).

Comment: Or avoid the compression pitfalls by subscribing to the uncompressed topic .../depth/image_rect_raw

Comment: thank you very much, I'll try this topic